# How to goto specific tag with some specific attribute in html using perl?

Tags: perl

I have tried using Table Extractor but I am not getting what I needed..

From this (http://finance.yahoo.com/q/pr?s=yhoo) html file i need to get company address that is present in td with class="yfnc_modtitlew1" which in table with id = "yfncsumtab"

```
use LWP::Simple;
use HTML::Parser;
use HTML::TokeParser;
use HTML::TableExtract;

my $file= "Tickers\\EBAY\\EBAY_profile.html";

my $te = HTML::TableExtract->new( attribs => { id => "yfncsumtab" });
$te->parse_file($file);
$te->tables;
my  @arr;
foreach my $row ($te->rows) 
{
   push @arr,@$row;
   print @$row ;
}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think your table is setup in a way that makes TableExtract the right tool.  TableExtract essentially turns a table into an Excel spreadsheet, then you retrieve data using row and/or column numbers, e.g. `cell(0, 4)`. You can't pick out rows by their id attributes.

TableExtract is for tables such as:

```
            Q1      Q2    Q3
teamA       10      20    30
teamB       40      50    60
teamC       70      80    90
```

In fact, the yahoo html coders are misusing tables for non tabular data--but yahoo is old school.

However, the row you are targeting is the second row of the table, so you *could* use TableExtract on your html like this:

```
use strict;
use warnings; 
use 5.020;
use LWP::Simple;
use HTML::TokeParser::Simple;
use HTML::TableExtract;
use Data::Dumper;

my $url = "http://finance.yahoo.com/q/pr?s=yhoo";
my $html_string = get($url) or die "Couldn't download webpage!";

my $target_table_id = "yfncsumtab";

my $table_extractor = HTML::TableExtract->new(
    attribs => { id => $target_table_id },
);

$table_extractor->parse($html_string);

my $table = $table_extractor->first_table_found()
    or die "No matching tables!";

my $text = $table->cell(1, 0);  #second row, first column
my @lines = split "\n", $text, 5; 

for my $line (splice @lines, 0, 4) {
    say $line;
}

__END__
Yahoo! Inc.
701 First Avenue
Sunnyvale, 
        CA 94089
```

Answer (score 1):

One way is via the excellent [XML::LibXML module](https://metacpan.org/release/XML-LibXML).  While you may think the module would accept only well-formed XML, it turns out that - as explained in this equally excellent [tutorial](http://grantm.github.io/perl-libxml-by-example/html.html) by **Grant McLean** - ;

*In fact, the parser has an HTML mode that handles unclosed tags like `<img>` and `<br>` and is even able to recover from parse errors caused by poorly formed HTML.*

To do that, you pass in a true value to the recover flag on the constructor;

```
my $url = 'http://finance.yahoo.com/q/pr?s=yhoo' ;
my $dom = XML::LibXML->load_html(
    location => $url ,
    recover  => 1  ,
);
say $dom->toStringHTML();
```

One can use the snippet above to verify successful fetching of the URL.  This will produce any errors on STDERR, so having verified you have got the data, run it again redirecting the output to the null device, `./script > /dev/null`, so that you can see what errors LibXML is finding in the HTML.

Having done that and satisfied yourself that nothing major is being passed over, you can add the `suppress_errors` flag to the constructor and use an XPATH query to pull out the data you are after;

```
use v5.12;
use XML::LibXML;

my $url      = 'http://finance.yahoo.com/q/pr?s=yhoo' ;
my $table_id = "yfncsumtab" ;
my $td_class = "yfnc_modtitlew1" ;
my $xpath    = sprintf  '//table[@id="%s"]//td[contains(@class, "%s")]' ,
                        $table_id , $td_class ;

my $dom = XML::LibXML->load_html(
    location => $url ,
    recover  => 1  ,
    suppress_errors => 1
);
# say $dom->toStringHTML();

for my $td ($dom->findnodes($xpath)) {
    say $_->textContent  for $td->childNodes ;
}
```

Rather than explain this in great detail, I can't do better than to again refer you to Grant's tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

You need to iterate over the tables, then the rows:

```
foreach my $table ($te->tables) {
    foreach my $row ($table->rows) {
       push @arr, @$row;
       print @$row;
    }
}
```